# How can I use line-height without affecting caret height?

Tags: css, html

In a contenteditable div I'm using line-height to add some line space when I have multiple lines. This is a sample div showing the issue:

```
<div style="padding: 50px; width: 90px; line-height: 2em;" contenteditable="true">
  line height line height line height
  <span style="line-height: 1em; color: Red;">line height</span>
  <span style="line-height: 10px; color: Orange;">line height</span>
  <span style="line-height: normal; color: Green;">line height</span>
  <span style="line-height: .5em; font-size: .5em; height: 5px; color: Blue;">line height</span>
</div>
```

In Chrome the caret height gets larger when you move the caret to the second line. I've added some spans in the div with different line heights, but that doesn't affect the caret height at all.

In Safari I see the same problem. In Firefox it works as expected, i.e. the caret height matches the font size, not the line height.

Is there any way to get around this problem in Chrome and Safari?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `<span>` is a generic inline container for phrasing content and (consequently) has no height.

If you declare all `<spans>` as having `display:inline-block` the caret will resize, accordingly:

```css
div {
padding: 50px;
width: 90px;
line-height: 2em;
}

div span {
display:inline-block;
}

div span:nth-of-type(1) {
line-height: 1em;
color: Red;
}

div span:nth-of-type(2) {
line-height: 10px;
color: Orange; 
}

div span:nth-of-type(3) {
line-height: normal;
color: Green; 
}

div span:nth-of-type(4) {
line-height: .5em;
font-size: .5em;
height: 5px;
color: Blue;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  line height line height line height
  <span>line height</span>
  <span>line height</span>
  <span>line height</span>
  <span>line height</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Rounin do you have suggestions for this caret problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866992/how-can-i-use-line-height-without-affecting-caret-height

Answer (score 1):

Try using `padding` instead of `line-height` and change `display` to `inline-block`:

```
<span style="padding: 10px 0; display: inline-block;">padding</span>
```

Comment: The height of a line box is determined by the height of the inline-level boxes it contains. For inline boxes like `span`, that's their `line-height`, and `padding` is ignored. See [Line height calculations](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#line-height)

Comment: @Oriol Thanks, I added `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: That will work if each line can be wrapped in an inline-block (or block). But that will be difficult, specially given that it's contenteditable.

Comment: Hi @Oriol do you by chance have any suggestions for this caret problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866992/how-can-i-use-line-height-without-affecting-caret-height